# WinHttp Gets 404 File Not Found

Tags: c++, winhttp

I am grabbing a webpage with WinHttp and the resulting page is the site's 404 file not found page.  I know that the code works as I have tested it with other websites.  The page in question is a normal http protocol and .html file.

What can I do?

Comment: Thank you - the http trace solved things.  I had specified the wrong flag and winhttp was trying to use https.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You don't give a whole lot to go on. I'd probably start with a trace of the HTTP session from your `WinHttp` calls and compare it with a trace from a working browser-based session and see what's different.  Could be anything from a cookie to a `referer` field to who-knows-what that the server might not like.